# bash use ruby code and save as variable

Tags: ruby, bash, git

my end goal is to parse a visual studio team services ssh git url and use it to clone origin and my fork. I'm in windows and I use git bash I've made a few shell scripts to help me to clone it. Before when we used gitweb it was easy for me to parse as I could either run `git_clone myproject` or `git_clone myproject.git` or `git_clone git://ourgitserver.ourcompany.com/myproject.git` and the script would clone the above as origin and also add a remote with my user name in the form of `ssh://git@outgitserver.ourcompany.com/myproject.git` (and it handled name spaces well too). Well we started using vsts and I want to do the same thing.

The git_clone method changed a few times because of how people would tell/im/email me the link for the git project. I wanted to be able to just copy and paste it with minimal changes. thus far I have a simple `git_vsts_close` which requires two parameters the name of the project and the name of the repository. (in gitweb we would reference the namespace as vsts's project and the project would be vsts's repository). For the time being I'd like to take either the ssh url or the two parameters and do all the git things. in brief this is what i have so far

```
function git_vsts_clone {
    local projectName=$1
    local repositoryName=$2
    if MISSING_ARG "usage: git_vsts_clone <project name> <repositoryName>\n  projectName must be provided\n  repositoryName must be provided" $projectName; then return 1; fi;
    if MISSING_ARG "usage: git_vsts_clone <project name> <repositoryName>\n  projectName must be provided\n  repositoryName must be provided" $repositoryName; then return 1; fi;

    local gitServer="ssh://mycompany@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22/${projectName}/_ssh/${repositoryName}"
    local clonePath="/c/git/${projectName}/${repositoryName}"
    local user_name=${USER:-${USERNAME}}

    if [ ! -d $clonePath ]; then
        INFO "Cloning $gitServer"
        git clone $gitServer $clonePath || { ERROR "ERROR cloning $gitServer"; return 1;}

        pushd $clonePath

        INFO "Updating Submodules (gsui)"
        git submodule update --init

        INFO "adding user fork ${user_name}"
        git remote add $user_name $gitServer.$user_name
        git fetch $user_name

        popd
        INFO "Opening $clonePath in vscode"
    fi
    code $clonePath
}
```

last time when I tried to parse a url in bash I struggled with the whole split an item into an array. so I decided i'd try to use ruby (since it has a easy split method) so i've tried things like

```
$ gitServer='ssh://mycompany@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22/someProject/_ssh/myRepo'
$ ruby -e "a = '$gitServer'; b=a.split('/'); p b"
["ssh:", "", "mycompany@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22", "someProject", "_ssh", "myRepo"]
$ foo=`ruby -e "a = '$gitServer'; b=a.split('/'); p b"`
$ echo "${c[3]}"

$ echo "${c[0]}"
["ssh:", "", "mycompany@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22", "someProject", "_ssh", "myRepo"]
```

so I dunno. I don't have to use ruby it just seemed like a easy solution... now not so much. So how can I get the project and repository name out of the url in either bash or bash using ruby?

Comment: I think you could probably state your question much more simply. That would help me and others get to it quickly to respond. You could probably omit all the history and context and simply provide the input and your desired output.

Comment: sorry I wanted to show that I had given it some effort instead of it seeming like I was "asking for teh codez"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way you can get the values into environment variables using Ruby:

Assuming you have a URL environment variable containing the git repo url, such as created by the line below:

```
export URL='ssh://mycompany@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22/someProject/_ssh/myRepo'
```

You can do the following to put your desired values into other environment variables:

```
export PROJECT=`ruby -e "puts ENV['URL'].split('/')[3]"`
export REPO_NAME=`ruby -e "puts ENV['URL'].split('/')[5]"`
```

Comment: That worked great. The only difference I did was `local PROJECT=...` and `local REPO_NAME=...`

Comment: You could also write a Ruby script to output things like `export PROJECT=...` and then import it, couldn't you? That would allow you to define multiple inputs at once.

Comment: @tadman What would that look like? The Ruby script would output the export commands as a single (probably multiline) string? Would you then need to redirect its output to a file, and then source that file? Seems to me that would be a good solution if performance were critical, but would add more complexity than it's worth in this case.

Comment: If the Ruby script outputs valid shell statements it should be importable. That is the output would be one `export X=y` per line such that if you saved that output into `variables.sh` and imported it then it would work.